# Running PHP with `-r` instead of code tags

Tags: discussion, scoring, php

Based on [this manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php), there is a `-r` option that allows you to run PHP code on the command line without specifying the code tags, `<? ?>`.

I recommended it on the polyquine question, where [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/37475/29438) code be considered a PHP quine if we used `-r` or `-R`. I'm pretty sure `-R` is used like `php -R scriptname.php` or something and then runs the script like it is in between code tags.

Coming from a Perl background, one-liners are often used to shorten the code. My answer [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/37113/29438) is an example. The way we have been counting it for Perl one-liners are:

- Each characters between the single quotes counts as a character.
- Each additional flag counts as a character.

I put `^` under each character we count for the following one-liner just as an example:

```
echo "test" | perl -nle'print'
                    ^^  ^^^^^
```

which would count as 7 characters.

For PHP, can we do the same thing? For example in this program from that manual:

```
$ php -r '$foo = get_defined_constants(); var_dump($foo);'
```

We would count the characters in between `'`.

I think you'd be able to shorten [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40545/29438) with the trick.

There was a small discussion in the comments [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40486/29438) about it.

- Would the `-r` count as 0, 1, or 2 characters?
- Is this allowed?
- Should I recommend this when I see answers with `<? ?>`?

I am not the best at PHP so I'm looking for some guidance.

Comment: By the way, the `?>` isn't necessary at the end of the file, and it's recommended not to use it because whitespace after it could start output (and prevent setting headers) before you want to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`perl -e` seems to be accepted without character penalty, so `php -r` should be OK as well.

`php -R` is the equivalent to `perl -ne`, so `php -R scriptname.php` is a syntax error.

`php -f file`, `php -F file` and plain `php file` all execute `file`, but none of them removes the need for PHP tags.

In `php -R code` or `php -F file`, the flag should be counted as one byte, just as in `perl -ne`.

Comment: I think that if `php -r` does not have any character penalties, than `php -R` should not have any character penalties. In Perl, you can do `perl -E` instead of `-e` to get the features for `say` for free, which lets you save 2 bytes over using `print`. Thanks for the explanation of `-R` too!

Comment: @chilemagic: Frankly, I'm not a fan of not counting the `-E` switch. For PHP, in my opinion, you can't get `-r` *and* `-R` for free. That basically allows yoo to have a single program performing two different tasks without any penalty in the score. `php -r` is the default for running code as a command-line argument, so any other switch should count.

Comment: Perhaps I'm a bit of a traditionalist, but a particular code cannot be saved to saved to a file, and executed thusly, then in my opinion it is not a _program_, but rather a code snippet.

Comment: @primo `<?` is rather a shebang than part of the code. Would you accept a shell script that does not start with `#/bin/sh`? @chilemagic: I agree partially: `-B` and `-E` add addional code, so at least the code should not be free. (@ all: Not sure about the flag itself. Can´t I just add that code to my program?) `-r` however only allows you to get rid of the shebang (like using `csh <someshellscript` instead of just using the default shell) and should not count.

Comment: @Titus `Happy new year <?=date(Y)?>!`.

Comment: @primo This is php mixed with plain text; I would consider that a disqualifying loophole.

Comment: @Titus _"This is php mixed with plain text"_ The default behavior is to dump everything to stdout. This is php.

Comment: @primo: It may be (historical) php, but I wouldn´t call it coding. Haven´t seen a php script in years that does not start off with `<?php`. Have You?

Comment: @Titus That's completely irrelevant. The language does what it does, and PHP prints everything outside of PHP tags verbatim to STDOUT.

Comment: ... unless you call it with `-r`, where any php tags are forbidden.