# How to answer a Code Golf Puzzle

Tags: discussion, code-golf, scoring

In some languages such as PHP you need to add these `<?php ?>` before you can start to program in PHP. And in C++ too. `int main(){}`. When answering a question, must I add the tags/function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PHP, no. With the `-r` flag, you can run the code without surrounding tags. [The `-r` switch doesn't contribute to the byte count](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2428/12012) in this case.

For C, you have two options:

1. Submit a full program.

   This requires a *main* function.
2. Submit a function.

   By default, all submissions may be full programs or functions. For compiled languages, a function is *usually* shorter, especially if you stick to C89 and use a permissive compiler such as gcc.

   For example, to add two numbers, the function

   ```
   f(a,b){return a+b;}
   ```

   is considered a valid submission.

If you enjoy golfing in C, [Tips for golfing in C](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2203/12012) is a good read.

Comment: For C++ you can also submit a lambda.